# find_java.exe not recognised - in Android SDK manager...while Java 8 update installed

Tags: java, android, eclipse, java-8, android-sdk-tools

I'm having a major issue with my SDK Manager.This arised when I updated my Java version to 8 from 7.While in this condition,I'm having Java 7 and 8 installed in my system.The path for both the Java versions are also set separately.

The console log in eclipse while opening the SDK Manager is given below:

> SDK Manager] [SDK Manager]
>   '"C:\ANDROI~1\ANDROI~2\ANDROI~1\tools\lib\find_java.exe" -s' is not
>   recognized as an internal or external command, SDK Manager] [SDK
>   Manager] operable program or batch file. SDK Manager] [SDK Manager]
>   '"C:\ANDROI~1\ANDROI~2\ANDROI~1\tools\lib\find_java.exe" -s -w' is
>   not recognized as an internal or external command, SDK Manager] [SDK
>   Manager] operable program or batch file. SDK Manager] [SDK Manager]
>   \Java\jre7\bin\java.exe"" was unexpected at this time.

The SDK is having all the versions up to an API level of 21.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

copy "java.exe" and "javaw.exe" file from "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\bin" to "C:\Windows\System32". Because sometimes during installation or updation these files are not reflected correctly.

Hope this helps.